# Detecting negative numbers using Javascript for developing a calculator

Tags: javascript, regex, calculator

I am developing a distributed calculator using JavaScript and PHP. The calculator should recognize parenthesis and should change the order of calculations according to parenthesis. All basic mathematical operations (`*`, `/`, `+`, `-`) have the same priority (unlike the common priority). I use the following regex to get user input and put in an array. This regex works well for positive numbers:

```
/\d*\.\d+|\d+|[()/*+-]/g
```

However, when it comes to **negative numbers**, it crashes because I use a recursive replacement function that replaces each pair of parenthesis (and the contents) with the result of the operations inside those parenthesis. I do this because this is a distributed calculator and I should perform each atomic operation at server side and then return the result back and show it in the history of the operations.

All I want is to detect negative numbers (to save them as only one element in the array). I think it should work in this way: when there are two consecutive operators (with zero or more whitespace characters between them), and the second operator is a minus sign (`-`), the minus sign should be concatenated to the following number (as the sign of the number). In addition, if the first number is preceded by a minus sign, the sign should be concatenated to that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no look-behind in javascript's implementation of regular expressions this is not as straightforward as it at first seems.

This is one way of doing it. It assumes that spaces have been stripped out first.

```
var m,
    tokens = [],
    rex = /(^|[(\/*+-])(-(?:\d*\.)?\d+)|[()\/*+-]|(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g,
    str = '-4-(-2*3)--4-2/-0.9-3+(3-4*-4)';

while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
    if ( m[1] ) {
        tokens.push( m[1], m[2] );
    } else {
        tokens.push( m[0] );
    }
}

console.log( tokens );
// [ "-4", "-", "(", "-2", "*", "3", ")", "-", "-4", "-", "2", "/", "-0.9", "-", "3", "+", "(", "3", "-", "4", "*", "-4", ")" ]
```

Here, the look-behind is emulated using capturing groups `()`. If there is the start of the string `^` or an operator `m[1]` before a negative number `m[2]`, then the operator and the negative number are each added to the array. Otherwise, any `-` is added to the array as an operator.

Alternatively, you could use

```
tokens = str.match( /(?:\d*\.)?\d+|[()\/*+-]/g );
```

and then iterate through the array, and if you find a `-` following an operator then prepend it to the following number.

Whichever way you do it, a simple regular expression will not tokenize the string alone, you will need to use a conditional statement to determine how to handle each `-`.